# php files are not working on server

Tags: php

i am recently doing one project that i face issue php files not working on server cpanel.

error : 
while php files are run shown below error

OUTPUT : 
No input file specified.

Comment: add your code here

Comment: all (.php) extension files are not visible the content while runing on live  Bro ..

Comment: http://ultrarmc.com/news-events.php

Comment: do you use an .htaccess ?

Comment: no i am not add .htaccess file so for

Comment: Let me guess - you've got some kind of form where a file can be uploaded and a `die('No input file specified')` somewhere in the code when that file isn't in the `POST` array...? Seriously, how is anyone supposed to know without seeing your code?

Comment: check the file permission of your document root.

Comment: @CD001   Bro the same error reflect all the .php file  , for example test.php  that contains only <?php echo 'hellow world.. ' ?> but it shows error ..    http://ultrarmc.com/test.php

Comment: @RamC exact digit for permission please Bro

Comment: run `ls -la test.php` and post ur output.

Comment: try `chmod 755 test.php`

Comment: Thank you for your support .. @CD001  and RamC  after clarify your comments 

am going to add .htaccess file , Now the files are working perfectly

Comment: did the permission change work ?

Comment: no bro i changed 755 but same error shows previously but now ok after adding .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the error is that PHP cannot find the file the server is telling it to look for.

It must be an issue with the .htaccess or insufficient file permission.

Check the .htaccess file.

Check the permission of the file. If it does not have read permissions, add it.

Hope it helps.